# Highcharts Gantt - Set max height and scrollbar on yAxis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I'm doing a project using Highcharts Gantt, and I'm having a little trouble mastering it at the moment, especially the management of its height and Y axis.

**Here Sandbox :** https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-microservice-fuv76?file=/src/GanttMain.jsx:334-352

Let me explain:
What I want to do is set a maximum height and use scrollablePlotArea to make the y-axis scroll, while keeping the X-axis header.

The problem is: if I define a minHeight in scrollablePlotArea, the Y axis cuts the events until the minimum height defined (see sandbox), if I increase minHeight, it will cut less events, but the number is dynamic, so impossible to put a fixed value...

My question is: How to define a maximum height, while keeping a Y scroll that displays all events, While not changing the line height?
I tried several possibilities with the documentation, but nothing works...

I hope I made myself understood...
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a bug in Highcharts Gantt and it is similar to this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13884

As a workaround you can dynamically set `minHeight` for scrollable plot area, example:

```
let allowChartUpdate = true;

Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    chart: {
        animation: false,
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minHeight: 450
        },
        events: {
            render: function() {
                if (allowChartUpdate) {
                    allowChartUpdate = false;

                    this.update({
                        chart: {
                            scrollablePlotArea: {
                                minHeight: ...
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    allowChartUpdate = true;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ywt2cmkn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/chart.events.render